# Char pointer assignment segment fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, variable-assignment

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
 char *str="abcdce";
 char c='c';
 char *pfast=str,*pslow=str;
 while(*pfast!='\0'){
     if(*pfast==c){
       pfast++;
       *pslow=*pfast; //error here when pfast reaches the first 'c'
     }
    pfast++;
    pslow++;
 }
 *pslow='\0';
 return 0;
}
```

segment fault when it runs to the assignment statement of "*pslow=*pfast;"...

Somebody tell me why, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean™ `pslow=pfast;`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to change a string literal which leads to undefined behavior.

Change

```
char *str="abcdce";
```

to

```
char str[] ="abcdce";
```

Comment: @witmusk: You are welcome. Since you are new and have not accepted answers to any of the questions you've asked so far, I would like to tell you that you can mark the answer that helped you to solve the problem by clicking the right mark next to the answer.